# How do I access my mysql database in Rails?

Tags: mysql

Say I have a database.yml that looks like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: arthouse_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  #socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

If this were postgres, all I need to do is type `psql arthouse_development`. What do I need to do here?

Also, it seems I have to type this everytime:

`mysql -u root` to just access `mysql`. Why is this? Can I configure this so that I don't have to do this everytime?

Answer (score 1):

You can save this line as shell script.

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword arthouse_development
```